# Restrict Openstack Instance ssh access

Tags: shell, openstack

I am creating a Openstack instance. Instance creation is successful but I need to restrict the access to the instance like I have assigned Instance1 to a scrum team some_scrum_team and want to restrict access to Instance1 to all the users apart from users in some_scrum_team.

I have created a Instance and not getting any option to restrict users to an Instance.

Instance should be accessible to only assigned users or mail alias.

Comment: Are you referring to access via the Horizon dashboard or being able to log in to the actual instance? If the latter, is it Windows or Linux?